# Relativity with imaginary speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

When deriving the form of Lorentz boosts, one arrives at a point where one proves that there is a real number $k$ such that the matrix of any transformation, in a relevant basis, should be $\begin{pmatrix}\gamma &-\alpha\gamma\\
-k\alpha\gamma&\gamma\\
\end{pmatrix}$ where $\alpha$ is the "speed" of the boost and $\gamma$ is the "Lorentz factor".

The composition law of $\alpha$'s is then given by $\alpha \oplus \alpha' := \frac{\alpha+\alpha'}{1+k\alpha\alpha'}$.

In the reference where I learnt this, it follows like this:

- if $k=0$, one gets the Galilean transformations;
- if $k>0$, one gets the Lorentz transformations and $k$ should be identified with the inverse of the square of the speed of light;
- if $k<0$, then *it doesn't make any sense, if suitable positive $\alpha$'s are chosen, one can make $\alpha \oplus \alpha'$ infinite or negative* and $k$ cannot be interpreted as the inverse of the square of the speed of light (unless the speed of light is imaginary).

However, it is straighforward to see that if $k<0$, the $\oplus$ law is isomorphic to the usual addition in $\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Z}$, the isomorphism being $\alpha \mapsto \arctan \left(\alpha\sqrt{-k}\right)$ (so it is possible to make sense of this case: the speeds should just be added in some circular way and two right-wise speeds can add up to a left-wise one).

My question is: does this (physically irrelevant, I agree) weird geometry have a name?

EDIT: Apparently, Greg Egan has studied what this spacetime would look like and has written fiction books located in it; see [here](http://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/ORTHOGONAL.html). So, maybe this geometry should just be named "orthogonal"?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#From_group_postulates) the proof you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it! I am a bit disappointed by the sentence "there would be transformations (with κv2 ≫ 1) which transform time into a spatial coordinate and vice versa. We exclude this on physical grounds, because time can only run in the positive direction" since I don't really understand what is meant here.